# How to use Google Maps to launch an activity when the user is away from a point a certain distance?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-activity, locationlistener

I am part of a project where we are using Google Maps to implement a tour of a few buildings in the area. 
My team and I are all beginners so we don't have extensive knowledge of programming android, however 
We would like to use Google Maps, and then by detecting the location of the user if he/she is close to a certain point we would like Google Maps to launch a certain activity.
Is this possible? and if so how can this be done?
Currently we have a Google Maps activity which has been automatically created by Android Studio and we have set it up to start at a particular location with a particular zoom level.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `LocationManager` to get the update of your user location and launch an intent (and stop monitoring the location) if the distance between user and the building are less than some number.

Answer (score 0):

From reading your requirement, I don't think you really need Google Maps. What you need is Geofences that will notify you the user is at some specified area, and perform actions like launching a new Activity.

Android doc on geofencing: http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

You can also try some example [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Geofencing) and [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/Geofencing).

Answer (score 0):

As said above, you need Location Updates so that you can get your location. And geofencing is used to detect transitions when you enter or exit a region. Geofencing registers a pending intent (intent is a message) which gets fired as soon as you enter or exit a particular region. When that happens, you can code your application to start a certain activity.Please check the topic **Handling Geofence Transitions** at [link](http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html)